# FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory. (Python_pygame)

Tags: python, pygame

I am a programming beginner. I recently had a problem with Python when running pygame that said:

> FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory.

I wanted to add an image that came out. This is my code here in case someone can help.

```py
current_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
resource_path = os.path.join(current_path, 'resources ') 
image_path = os.path.join(resource_path, 'images')

#Knight
knight = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image_path, 'nicti.png'))
```

Answer (score 0):

`os.path.dirname(path)` just the first element of the pair returned by passing path to the function [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.split).
Use `os.path.abspath()` to return a normalized absolutized version of the path:

<s>`current_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)`</s>

```py
current_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, as long as your image is in the same folder as your program, you could just go:

```
knight = pygame.image.load('knight.png')
```

If it is in a subfolder, (I usually have a folder called textures for images):

```
knight = pygame.image.load(r'textures\knight.png')
```

So yours will be (as long as it is in the same folder as your program):

```
knight = pygame.image.load(r'resources\images\knight.png')
```

No fancy stuff